# Is $BB^{\top}+ c I$ an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be an $n\times m$ real matrix, $c$ be a positive constant, and $I$ be the identity.

Is $B\cdot B^{\mathrm T} + cI$ guaranteed to be invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can check that $BB^T+cI$ is positive definite; its eigenvalues are all at least $c>0$.  So it is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

$BB^T$ for any $B$ is symmetric semi-positive definite (see explanation below), which means that its eigenvalues are all $\geq 0$. Adding $cI$ shifts "to the right" all the spectrum by $c$, thus all eigenvalues become $>0$. And, as this operation preserves symmetry, the resulting matrix est symmetric positive definite.

Explanation : for any (vertical) vector $X \in \mathbb{R^n}$,

$$X^T(BB^T)X= (B^TX)^T(B^TX)=\|B^TX\|^2 \geq 0$$

which is a criterion for semi definite positiveness of matrix $BB^T$.